# Example of a linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb{C}$ with $\text{null }T = \text{range }T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

**Question.** 
 Let $V = \mathbb{C}$. and $F = \mathbb{R}$. Construct a linear operator $T$ on $V$ such that the null space of $T$ is identical to the image of $T$. Justify your example.

**My Question(s).** 
 First, is it correct that the first sentence should be interpreted as, "Treat $\mathbb{C}$ as a two dimensional vector space, the components of each vector being real numbers." Second, if so, would $T(x,y) = (0,x)$ be an acceptable operator? Third, if so, would it be correct to write this as $T(x + iy) = ix$?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks good to me. The image and the kernel are both the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you gave a nice example. I will try to be as precise as possible, probably pedantic, because I think it could be of interest for you.

1. "Treat $\mathbb C$ as a two dimensional vector space, the $\mathbf {components}$ of each vector being real numbers."

I would say the coefficients of each vector is a real number, $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$ or $\mathbb N ^{\infty}$ have components

2. "Second, if so, would $T(x,y)=(0,x)$ be an acceptable operator?"

$T$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, not on $\mathbb C$, but I can see what you intend, you are considering the standard isomorphism $S$ between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$ such that $S(1)=(1,0)$ and $S(i)=(0,1)$

3. " if so, would it be correct to write this as $T(x+iy)=ix?$"

Yes, this is how I would write the solution to the exercise, because what you are doing is actually considering the base $\{1,i\}$ of $V=\mathbb C$ with field $F=\mathbb R$.